# Integrator and the multiplier in the Optimal Binary Detector

Tags: signal-detection, demodulation

The optimal binary detector for asymmetric, equiprobable PAM pulse normally have structure as shown below,

[image]

But I cannot understand what is the multiplier and the integrator using for.

- Why the detector need to care the signal difference and multiply with the received signal?
- Why can't I directly put the received signal to the threshold comparsion?

Comment: Whate are s_1(t) and s_2(t) in your diagram?

Comment: Two different signal, s_1(t)= A and s_2(t) = -A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things missing/extra in your diagram.

- What you are using is 
  rectangular PAM pulses of duration $T$ to send data across the channel, and so 
  you really don't need the multiplier. It is necessary only if $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$
  are different from rectangular pulses (though they are still of duration $T$, 
  and in that case, the input $s_1(t)-s_2(t)$ to the multiplier does not tell 
  the whole story.
- The integrator that you are using is really what is called an 
  **integrate-and-dump** correlator. The input is 
  integrated over *intervals* of time $[(n-1)T, nT)$. *Just before the end of
  the integration period*, at time $nT^{--}$, the integrator output is *sampled*
  and the sample value is what is used in the threshold device. Following
  the sampling at $nT^{--}$, the integrator is *dumped* (meaning that 
  the output is *reset* to $0$) at time $nT^{-}$, and the integrator is
  *restarted* at $t = nT$ for the next data bit from $nT$ to $(n+1)T$.
  Note that there is what computer engineers call a *critical race* involved:
  the circuit designer has to make absolutely sure that the *sample* signal 
  arrives at the integrator *before* the *dump* signal. Getting this wrong
  can be a fireable offense.
- With the integrate-and-dump correlator working as described above,
  the input to the multiplier during $[(n-1)T, nT)$ needs to be
  $s_1(t-(n-1)T)-s_2(t-(n-1)T)$, that is, the signal $s_1(t)-s_2(t)$
  (which is nonzero only for $t \in [0,T)$) delayed by $(n-1)T$ seconds.
- What the integrate-and-dump correlator is doing is computing the
  output of the *matched filter* for signals $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$
  in additive white Gaussian noise at times $nT$.  Note that the
  correlator output is *not* equal to the matched filter output
  at times other than $nT$.
- The reason you cannot simply sample the received signal
  and make a decision from the sample is that the SNR is abysmal.
  Technically, AWGN has infinite variance 
  (cf. [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8629/235)),
  but even otherwise this is a big problem.  The matched
  filter maximizes the SNR at the sampling instants,
  and the correlator is just calculating what the matched
  filter will give you at the sampling instants.

For details of all this, see, for example, pp. 85-93
of these [ancient lecture notes](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece461/spring98/book1/Matched_Filters.pdf) of mine.