# Matched Filter of Gaussian Signal

Tags: filters, gaussian

How can we evaluate the matched filter's impulse response of a Gaussian function $x(t) = \exp(-\frac{t^2}{2})$. As far as we know, for a signal of finite duration $T$, the impulse response of it's matched filter is $h(t) = x(T-t)$. But as Gaussian function is of infinite duration, how can we find the matched filter ?

Comment: gonna have to truncate it somewhere.  because $e^{-t^2}$ dies off quickly, that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: No signal that extends out to $\infty$ can have a _causal_ matched filter. With a causal filter, at any finite time $T$, there is still signal that has not been processed by the filter as yet, and so by waiting a little bit longer, you can always improve performance.  That being said, one can define **the** matched filter for any $x(t)$ as the filter with impulse response $x(-t)$ (see, e.g. [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9389/235)). For _your_ Gaussian function, try something like $$h(t) = \begin{cases} \exp\left(-\frac{(t-3)^2}{2}\right), &t \geq 0,\\0, &t<0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter

the derivation does not depend on the filter being either causal or have a finite duration. The derivation is fully satisfactory for convolution for time index $k$ over $-\infty,\infty$.  It's all about what filter will maximize the Schwarz inequality.

In this case 
$$
x(t)=\exp(-\frac{(t-0)^2}{2}) = x(0-t)
$$

Functions that are symmetric are their own matched filter.

The $T$ parameter enters the discussion in terms of when does one sample the filter for the purpose of detection.  If $x(t)$ was delayed by some unknown time(nonsynchronous detection),  I would use the matched filter to estimate it's delay.