# problem with the matched filter

Tags: digital-communications

Let $y(t)=s(t)+n(t)$

For the matched filter h(t) on $[0,T]$ we have, $h(t)=s(T-t)$.
And the output is:
$z(t)=\int_0^T y(u)h(t-u)du=\int_0^T y(u)s(t-(T-u))du=\int_0^T y(u)s(u-(T-t))du$

But sometimes I see, $z(t)=\int_0^T y(u)s(u)du$. How do we get the last equation?

Comment: $t=T$ the convolution is at its maximum value

Answer (score 2):

$z(t)$ cannot possibly equal $\displaystyle \int_0^T y(u)s(u) \mathrm du$ unless $z(t)$ has *constant value* for all $t$: the value of the integral does not depend on $t$ at all!  Nor is your convolution integral correct.  If $s(t)$ is nonzero only for $t \in [0,T]$, then so is $h(t) = s(T-t)$ nonzero only for $t \in [0,T]$. Consequently, **for every real number** $t, -\infty < t < \infty$, the matched filter output $z(t)$ is given by
\begin{align}
z(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(u)h(t-u) \,\mathrm du\\
&= \int_{t-T}^t y(u)h(t-u) \,\mathrm du &{h(t-u) = 0~ \text{whenever}~u >t~\text{or}~ u < T-t}\\
&= \int_{t-T}^t y(u)s(u+(T-t)) \,\mathrm du\\
&= \int_{0}^T y(v+T-t)s(v) \,\mathrm dv.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Now, when $t$ **equals** $T$, we get that the matched filter output **at time** $t=T$ is
$$z(T) = \int_{0}^T y(v)s(v) \,\mathrm dv = \int_{0}^T y(u)s(u) \,\mathrm du.\tag{2}$$
Note clearly the difference between your $\displaystyle z(t) = \int_0^T y(u)s(u) \mathrm du$ and what you (or your textbook author) *should* have written, namely $(2)$.

As @Stanley Pawlukiewicz points out, the matched filter output has a maximum value at $t=T$.  For this result, (and far more than you probably want to know about matched filters), see [this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9389/235) on this site.