# signals and systems,matched filter concept

Tags: convolution, matched-filter

[image]

The system with impulse response hi(t) is known as the matched filter
for the signal Xi(t) because the impulse response is tuned to xi(t) in order to
produce the maximum output signal.
[image]
My intuition says for y(4) to be maximum,x(t)=h(-t+4).
But I can not come up with a more rational mathematical proof.Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please do your own homework, bypassing that doesn’t really help you. But if there is something you don’t understand after you have done all the prerequisite investment of your own time we’re happy to help with ours.

Comment: @DanBoschen I have uploaded my approach to the question sir,can you please tell me if my approach is correct. Or can you suggest me how to approach the problem in a better way

Comment: It looks like Hilmar has helped you! Thanks for the update

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9389/235).

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, so here is a hint:

Since these are all binary functions with time step of one (and I'm too lazy to type integrals), I'm just going to treat it like a sum with the index being the end-time. So you get

$$y(4) = h(1)\cdot x(4) + h(2)\cdot x(3) + h(3)\cdot x(2) + h(4)\cdot x(1) $$

Given that both $|h| \le 1$ and $|x| \le 1$ it should be pretty obvious what's the largest that $y(4)$ can be and what you need to do to each individual term to get the max result.

Caveat: I'm using very sloppy notation here, so please don't use that in your solution.