# A Machine Learning Based Algorithm as an Alternative to the Matched Filter

Tags: signal-detection, estimation, machine-learning, deep-learning, parameter-estimation

Consider we have to detect a known signal added with Gaussian noise. In this scenario, the matched filter is known to be an optimal filter for SNR. The question: is there any machine learning algorithm/tool that can be used instead of matched filter? Can we have any other detection technique instead of filter (convolution)?

Comment: Interesting. Marking to answer this with a nice experiment :-).

Comment: @Royi Thank you, I would love to see the result.

Comment: @Royi I know we did quite a few of these at our institute, couple years back: students demonstrating a NN learning the optimal receive processing for a nonlinear channel converging against the matched filter as one reduces the channel nonlinearity, students demonstrating the matched filter can not only be learned with classical (R)NN architectures but also spiking neural networks … these kinds of things.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Could you share paper? Code? Interesting. Well, for the detection part the Matched Filter indeed optimal at any SNR. But we use Matched Filter for other objectives as well. While it is still great, we might beat it for some cases...

Comment: @Royi lemme check what is publicly available

Comment: @Royi OK, let's start with this, because it's a publication that was based on work my Prof had done with his prior employer: https://opg.optica.org/jlt/abstract.cfm?uri=jlt-36-20-4843 not *actually* about matched filters, but about "how do I get the best error rates / highest data rates in a nonlinear channel through machine learning". It's pretty cool how far the found solution *generalizes*, i.e. for what range of distances a net trained for a single distance (but some variation) still works!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Thanks for sharing. I am not that proficient with the optics communication lingo but I will give it a try.

Comment: @Royi shouldn't be too bad, I hope!  terms you need to know: 1. IM/DD: Intensity Modulation/Direct Detection: Essentially, you ASK the output of a laser diode (i.e. a 100-Terahertz carrier) at the transmitter, and the receiver is a (tuned) photodiode. That has a rectifying/exponential characteristic, so it's a bit like a 1920 crystal radio detector :D. 2. CD: Chromatic dispersion: yeah, the fiber isn't a linear-phase system. Different frequencies (colors!) have different group velocity -> chromatic dispersion, eq. (11).

Comment: What time-independent detection technique would you use other than a filter? And if you make it time-dependent... then it's time-dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to have a simple experiment to see if we can get, for a known signal, a better results than the Matched Filter for time delay estimation.

### Experiment Objective

Generate, using ML (DL), a system which estimates time delay under the model of a shifted signal with *Additive Gaussian White Noise* (AWGN).

### Experiment Motivation

It is known that the performance Matched Filter for time delay estimation is far from the CRLB at Low SNR scenario. It is not known if the CRLB is too optimistic (As it isn't guaranteed to be a tight lower bound) or the Matched Filter (MLE for this case) is not optimal for such case. This could be some kind of an empirical way to assess which one of the alternatives is more probable.

### Optimality of the Matched Filter

Pay attention that the Matched Filter is the global optimum for detection by being the operation, linear or non linear, which maximizes the SNR (Easy to prove with Cauchy Schwartz). Yet this optimality is in the context of detection (There is or no signal of interest). This experiment is about estimating the delay of the signal.

### Data

I created a simple Gaussian signal:

[image]

The signal is built with 201 samples.

Then I created `1,000,000` signals with shifted versions of the signal with various levels of added noise (The noise STD was in the range of `[0, 1]`).

For example, here is a shifted and noisy signal:

[image]

In he above, the signal was shifted by 3 samples. In order to make things easier I kept the shift to be an integer. It was done to prevent the need to create interpolation phase, etc...
The support of the shifted signal was 300 samples. Hence we had 100 different possible shifts (1 to 100).

I created 2 data sets: Train (1,000,000 signals) and Test (100,000 signals).

I created the simplest 1D CNN using Keras:

```py
modelNet = keras.Sequential()
modelNet.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(32, vSignal.shape[0], activation = 'relu'))
modelNet.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(48, 51, activation = 'relu'))
modelNet.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 25, activation = 'relu'))
modelNet.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 13, activation = 'relu'))
modelNet.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
modelNet.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 100, activation = 'softmax'))
```

The above is classification network, basically having to choose between 100 classes (Each per shift).

Trained it for 21 Epochs and got accuracy of `30.05%` (Some checkpoint got even better):

[image]

Now, what would the Matched Filter do?

[image]

It gets `29.52%`. So the 1D CNN got `0.5%` more accuracy. Not bad for `~60` minutes work.

Let's have a look on the per signal performance of all:

[image]

In the above we see the best check point of the net training.

Zooming in to a specific delay (38):

[image]

The interesting thing is that the Matched Filter doesn't miss at high SNR (The left part). Since the overall of the 1D CNN is better it means it mainly beats it in lower SNR.

This validates my assertion, one could beat the Matched Filter for time delay estimation in the Low SNR zone and a great candidate to do so is using CNN.
By the way, even in the RMSE the Matched Filter was beaten by the 1D CNN (`2.6954` vs `2.7771`).

Few remarks:

- Pay attention that the 1D CNN didn't get any information about the signal itself (The reference). Result would be better if it did. One way to do it, the simplest, is to let it work on the cross correlation data. In my opinion well tweaked model working on the cross correlation can get over 35%.
- The experiment should be done for a regression model with fractional delay. Though it is valid for cases the quantization holds (For instance if the sampling frequency is high enough).

Comment: Why would someone -1 this? I don't get it...

Comment: Maybe it should be a comment below the OP's post?

Comment: I didn't vote down your answer btw

Comment: @Royi because it's not an answer.

Comment: But it is an answer in progress. I am not done.

Comment: @Royi An answer in progress is not an answer.

Comment: (I didn't downvote) GPS is an excellent example of applying the matched filter under negative SNR conditions, so I don't think there is any restriction to medium and high SNR conditions- and why use a matched filter at  all for a high SNR case?? My understanding is that the matched filter regardless of SNR is optimum specifically under the condition of white noise. Showing that this case specifically is not optimum would be interesting; for any other noise conditions or non-linear, non-stationary channels it is well understood that the matched filter would no longer be the optimum solution.

Comment: @DanBoschen "for any other noise conditions or non-linear, non-stationary channels it is well understood that the matched filter would no longer be the optimum solution" -- certainly, the conventional matched filter would not be optimum, but there could still be _a_ filter, designed for those specific conditions, that is optimum (just like the MF is designed for AWGN). Optimum filtering is like channel capacity: you need to calculate it for your specific channel, and the usual formula only applies to a specific channel.

Comment: @MBaz Yes agreed but the question is about the Matched Filter specifically. My point was specific to the traditional definition of "matched filter" as the complex conjugate of the template for the transmitted waveform using LTI filters.

Comment: @DanBoschen I understand and I agree with you -- my point is just that "matched filter" can be given a broader, more general meaning, as "the filter that maximizes SNR for a given pulse shape and a given channel".

Comment: @MBaz Ah I am with you now, yes good point. It doesn't sound like that is related the OP's question however since he conditions it as for a known signal with an AWGN channel. But if we make the question different, we would get a different answer. So my comment here was for Royi's interesting experiment in case it would have a different conclusion from what Marcus already answered (which would then change the current understanding and be very interesting).  If the experiment was for some other case, then it would just confuses the question at hand

Comment: @DanBoschen, You may plot the variance of the delay estimation by a Matched Filter against the CRLB. You'll see there is a gap for lower SNR. My experiment will target the case of Low SNR in the classic case of Matched Filter.

Comment: @Royi interesting! Why is that the case? (Maybe that’s another question ) looking forward to seeing your sim

Comment: @DanBoschen, I think in most cases the ML estimators behave like that. Since their performance is mostly a function of the number of samples and for AWGN Number of Samples ~ effective SNR those methods work well for those cases. I will give the experiment a try. But of course it will be limited to what I can do in 30-60 minutes.

Comment: Can delay estimation problem poised as synchronization in wireless communications?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/47132)

Comment: @MBaz, It's not a full answer. It is a place holder at the moment. I'm running the experiments in the background.

Comment: @MBaz, It was a bad idea at first. But at least now it makes me commit to do it. So I guess it will be OK.

Comment: @Royi I don't see the point of announcing that you will provide an answer at some point... why not just post the answer when it's ready? Just my opinion, though.

Comment: @MBaz, As I wrote, I thought the time interval will be shorter, so as a reminder I put it. Now we both agree it wasn't the smartest thing to do. But don't judge it just yet :-).

Comment: @Royi, On your comment about maximum likelihood (ML) estimators: That gap is to be expected. The maximum likelihood estimator and the CRLB are both derived from the Fisher Information causing the ML estimator to asymptotically obtain the CRLB as you gain more information (e.g. collect more samples). This is known as asymptotic normality. It is possible that a different estimator more quickly tends toward the CRLB for certain conditions (medium SNR), which could be found using machine learning techniques, but I wouldn't expect a low SNR case to be *easily* out performed by machine learning.

Comment: @Ash, I just pointed the weaknesses of the Matched Filter. What you wrote is well know (See my comment above). I think the correct ML method will be better in the SNR's the Matched Filter is relatively far from the CRLB. Actually the real point is how far is the CRLB from the the real lower bound at those SNR's. The CRLB tends to be overly optimistic at times.

Comment: @PeterK., I updated the answer. I think it was worth the waiting :-). Hopefully people will remove their `-1`.

Comment: Oooh. Nice!  I didn't add a `-1` like two others did, but have a `+1` anyway! :-)

Comment: Is the result significant statistically? It appears to be just a sample outcome. I mean if the experiment is done again we may get another result and matched filter may turn out to be bettter.

Comment: @Creator, that's a good question. I used 100,000 samples. I haven't done analysis using Chebyshev's inequality and such but for this large number of samples I'd say it is real advantage. Pay attention that for higher SNR the gap is wider and the net I used is the simplest one could think of and still shows a proof of concept. The real mystery here is what the real lower bound. I am pretty sure the CRLB is too optimistic.

Comment: I speculate that 1D CNN has learned some "character" of the random generator of MATLAB. In that case, the result may be an artificial improvement.

Comment: @Creator, I find that hard to believe. If you suggest that the Matched Filter is the optimum, than you also have an answer to your question. So you win either way :-).

Comment: I am trying to replicate your results but I have not done much machine learning and never used Keras. I imported Keras model and layers but could not run the model. Would you please help or share your code?   After import I get :     modelNet = keras.Sequential()
NameError: name 'keras' is not defined

Comment: You said you would share your code, but that comment is deleted. May I ask if you would share or not?

Comment: @Creator, I will share it. I'm arranging it. But we have holiday so my time is limited. You may look at the Python code of the net training in `SignalProcessing/Q82711` at my StackExchange GitHub Repository - https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will wait for your codes.

Comment: Thank you for some code but not easy to replicate without the corresponding data as the structure of the data is not visible. But the code is gone now it seems.

Comment: What do you mean the code is gone? There is also the MATLAB script to generate the data at the same folder.

Comment: It was my mistake. I did not realize that the default page shows only the recent updates.

Comment: @Royi why did you use a CNN vs a NN here? If you are training each detection lag as its own class, you don't need the power of a CNN.

Comment: @BigBrownBear00, CNN is more efficient. It means we employ a prior of the correlation over time. Something dense layers will take time to make use of.

Comment: @Royi What you have here is pretty great, nice work. Have you considered the case where there might be `N` signals to detect? This approach, particularly the inference stage, could be significantly less computationally intensive compared to traditional bank of matched filters

Comment: @BigBrownBear00, Indeed. For multi target case I have no doubt this is the way to go. But there is a limit what can be done here :-).

Answer (score 9):

Sure, you can *learn* the matched filter, as convolution with a filter is just a function applied to a signal, and e.g. Neural Networks (through the *universal approximation theorem*) are good function approximators.

But the fact that the matched filter is optimal in AWGN channels means exactly that: it's optimal, you can't do better than it. So there's really no point, other than showing you *can* learn it, in learning it. The classical, analytical methods work, and their provably the best.

Interesting problems arise when you e.g. want to minimize error in cases the channel is not AWGN, your reception is irregularly quantized etc., i.e., in cases where the analytical derivation of an optimal receive processing does not exist (or only exists in high complexity).

Comment: Isn't the matched filter optimal only over the subset of linear filters, meaning that a non-linear filter could perform better than it in certain situations?

Comment: @JacopoTissino ah, we do have to constrain ourselves to AWGN as channel (in other situations the matched filter itself is not necessarily optimal). And in the AWGN channel, decision based on sampling the matched filter *is* maximum likelihood, so a nonlinear filter can't be better :)

Comment: Totally agree. Machine Learning is not a catch-all that would obsolete traditional signal processing. Machine Learning is best for solving the previously unsolvable problems. If used for problems that are already solved with other methods, machine learning will also solve it, but will much less efficiency. The Matched Filter under AWGN with stationary channel conditions is certainly not in that camp. However a matched for a non-linear and/or non-stationary channel (in such conditions that our traditional solutions are not yet optimum) may have promise with ML.

Comment: Reminds me of a paper which has crossed my table where authors spent three pages learning the linear least squares approximation with neural nets. It was about 0.3% "worse" on the training set than your regular least squares and about 0.2% "better" on the test one. Still trying to wrap my head around why'd people do that...

Comment: @Lodinn 1. it's a legitimate exercise to prove your learning architecture can learn! 2. Often, your end goal is not replicating a single element from a signal processing chain, but combine that with successive steps, either to build something that, through joint optimization does work better than the two separate things, or to then "prune" parts from your neural network, so that in the end the resulting NN algorithm is less complex than the classical method while still achieving approximately the same performance.

Comment: But yeah, there's power in recognizing that NNs are basically function approximators, but can be used to approximate functions we might not have a closed description for ("The function mapping pictures to cat- or dogalikeness", or "the function equalizing this nonlinear channel"), and that the description of what they can be optimized for can incorporate themselves / properties of themselves ("regularization" if you look at ML literature).

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not arguing it shouldn't be used when it's *less* complex, it's the alarming pattern of "shove AI/ML into the paper so there's a higher chance of acceptance" that is baffling to me. I'm spending a good part of the last few years teaching people to isolate the "black box" models which are typically used - basically, to just have a well-defined end goal rather than an exercise a student might do as a part of their course project. There's been a real lot of outright bad research with ML for the sake of ML in it, and it makes me worried. Am currently in biophysics.

Comment: if it helps, it looks like that wave is over: ML itself is a maturing field, and its applications in all possible fields reach a similar stage, where domain experts have enough knowledge in ML that you're not getting any credit just because you combine ML with anything.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Do you have a link to the optimal of matched filter? In what sense...

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin optimal in SNR as requested in the question! Matched filter maximizing SNR in the AWGN channel is subject of most digital communication basics textbooks. Currently not at my desk, but I'm sure it's in e.g. Proakis, and in Kammeyer, and in Sklar

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin in absence of a book I can link to, try [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/understanding-the-matched-filter) answer

Comment: @MarcusMüller, i see snr, what about detection? Maybe not a monotonic function of snr? you answer starts with the integral model -> linear model.

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin don't know what you mean with detection. If you read the answer closely, you'll notice that Cauchy-Schwarz shows this to lead to a maximum-likelihood decision, i.e. can't be better than that.