# Expectation of product of Filtered White Gaussian Noise

Tags: autocorrelation, gaussian

Assume I have a random process $X(t)$ that is white gaussian noise with psd $S(f)$.  Now, let's filter that noise through a LPF of bandwidth $B$.  How would I evaluate the following expression:

$$E[S(f_1)S(f_2)]$$

Comment: How does the LPF factor into your question?

Comment: The psd is limited to the range $[-B/2,B/2]$ instead of being infinite.

Comment: $S(f_1)$ and $S(f_2)$ are _not_ random quantities and so taking their expected values gives just $Sf_1)S(f_2)$. Since the expectation is pretty meaningless here, I am inclined to believe that what you want to know is something quite different from what you have written.

Answer (score 3):

In general, for an input signal $x$ with power-spectrum density $S_x(f)$ passed through a linear-time-invariant (LTI) system with transfer function $H(f)$, the power-spectrum density of the output, $S_y(f)$ is given by:

$$
  \begin{align}
    S_y(f) &= S_x(f)\left|H(f)\right|^2
  \end{align}
$$
A complete derivation can be found in various textbooks (such as "Communication Systems Engineering", by John G. Proakis and Masoud Salehi) and lecture notes (such as [these](http://www.idsc.ethz.ch/Courses/signals_and_systems/ArchiveFall10/lectureNotes8.pdf)). Note that a consequence of this result for Gaussian noise is also quoted [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/variance-of-white-gaussian-noise).

Thus, if evaluating the output PSD at $f_1$ and $f_2$, we have
$$
  \begin{align}
    S_y(f_1) &= S_x(f_1)\left|H(f_1)\right|^2 \\
    S_y(f_2) &= S_x(f_2)\left|H(f_2)\right|^2
  \end{align}
$$
And consequently,
$$
  \begin{align}
    E[S_y(f_1)S_y(f_2)]
      &= S_y(f_1)S_y(f_2) \\
      &= S_x(f_1)S_x(f_2)\left|H(f_1)H(f_2)\right|^2
  \end{align}
$$

Note that for an input consisting of white (or at least white over some finite observable bandwidth much greater than B) Gaussian noise with power-spectral density $N_0/2$, we get:
$$
  \begin{align}
    E[S_y(f_1)S_y(f_2)] &= \frac{1}{4} N_0^2\left|H(f_1)H(f_2)\right|^2
  \end{align}
$$