# How to calculate the noise power for a non-stationary noise?

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, stationary

With **stationary noise** we have constant mean and variance (let's assume it is Gaussian noise). My first question is, how is the noise power calculated and how it is related to the variance?

Now, I have a **non-stationary noise** which its variance is not constant and changes periodically over time. My second question is, how can I calculate the noise power for this noise and how it is related to the time-variant variance?

Any help and remark on the topic would be appreciated.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your signal is just $n(t)$ distributed as $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then the expected signal power is then:
$$
p_{\rm ensemble} = E\left [ \left| n(t) \right|^2 \right] = \mu^2 + \sigma^2
$$

For the time-varying case, I'd suggest that the answer is:
$$
p_{\rm time\ varying} = \mu^2(t) + \sigma^2(t)
$$

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you very much.

Comment: One question though, why they usually put $N_0$ as the noise power for a stationary WGN? Is that $N_0$ equal to the variance if the mean is zero?

Comment: $N_0$ is not the noise power. [It is the noise spectral density.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_spectral_density)  See [Dilip's answer here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8632/80) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Now everything is clear. I didn't know the relationship between variance and PSD. You were very helpful, thanks again.