# $E(X(t)X(t))=\sigma^2\delta(\tau)$ or $E(X(t)X(t))=\sigma^2$

Tags: noise, autocorrelation

(Question already asked on Math StackExchange)

Let's say we have a white noise process $x(t)$ such that:

$E(X(t)X(t+\tau))=N\delta(\tau)$

$E(X(t))=0$

In particular, with $\tau=0$, $E(X(t)X(t))=E(X^2(t))$ is infinite.

Now, I want $X(t)$ at each time $t$ to have a normal distribution of 0 mean and $\sigma^2$ variance. That is:

$E(X^2(t))=\sigma^2$

This is not consistent. I guess the expectations mean something different in both cases, but I don't find an explanation. This prevents me from moving ahead in a study of the mean, variance and autocorrelation of a process $y(t)$ defined as $y(t)=1$ if $a<x(t)<b$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/variance-of-white-gaussian-noise?

Comment: It is not considered good practice to post the same question on two different groups.  Be that as it may, you might want to read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134193/15941) (which _I_ asked) and its answers on math.SE. Basically, the answer I received is that while what you would like to have is desirable from your perspective and _is_ something that mathematicians have studied, it is not at all useful for _engineering applications_ such as the one you have in mind.

Comment: To complement other comments, this is the way I see this problem. The white noise process _does not_ have a variance. The good news is that we _never_ observe white noise directly; we always observe it through an instrument that has finite bandwidth. The _output_ of that instrument does have a variance, which can be calculated from the white noise PSD and the device's bandwidth and gain.